# Requirement of rs232,Is RS232 is compulsory for UART communication or not

Tags: communication

Is it compulsory to use RS232 with UART communication without using of RS232 ,UART communication is not possible?

Comment: You should have a look at the UART wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) which says you can use RS-232, RS-422 or RS-485. What would you like to use?

Answer (score 7):

Two UARTs can communicate directly with each other without using RS232, RS422 or RS485. If you want to extend the distance between two UARTs you have to think about the cable interface and this is where RS232, RS422 or RS485 come in. However there is nothing stopping you developing any type of cable interface specification but, keeping it to a world wide recognized standard, is usually beneficial because of availability of driver chips and solutions.

Answer (score 5):

A *UART* is a universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter. It is a functional block of logic that, given a clock and clock rate, supports some specific asynchronous serial protocol (or a small set of them that are usually quite similar) for transmitting characters, usually of 7 or 8 bits in length. It includes the concept of a *start bit*, *stop bit(s)*, and some number of data bits (typically 7 or 8.) It can be emulated in software and may use any electronic (or other) method of signalling one of two different symbols -- call them 0 and 1. It uses only these two symbols for communication, except that there is exactly one "out of band" symbol -- the *break* symbol -- which may also be recognized.

The term *UART* is usually applied to the most common form involving 7 or 8 data bits and the start and stop bits I mentioned, but it can have a meaning that may be unusual but still technically an asynchronous protocol. It is very common to see the term *USART* for functional blocks supporting some asynchronous and some synchronous protocols. (Not infrequently, within microcontrollers.)

(The function of a UART is independent of the signalling used for a 0 or 1 symbol. So much so, I suppose, that a human being could be a UART and watch someone using flags on a distant ship and signalling back using special flags to wave. I'm saying this to get the point across that the means of signalling isn't important. The protocol is about what to do with the signals that are received and what to do about sending data to another UART that shares the same functionality.)

RS-232 is a small family of electronic signalling specifications designed to cope with voltage noise while also defining two different symbols resulting from those electronic definitions -- the *mark* and the *space*. A *mark* is now defined to be any line voltage (referenced to the signal ground) from -3V to -15V (and must tolerate -25V) as a *mark*, any line voltage (referenced to the signal ground) from +3V to +15V (and must tolerate +25V) as a *space*, and voltages between -3V and +3V as undefined.

RS-232 is compatible with UART protocols because RS-232 defines a mapping between two defined states of electronic signalling and two symbols, *mark* and *space*. By simply agreeing to consider a *space* as a 0 and a *mark* as a 1, the mapping is complete and a UART is then compatible with RS-232.

But other electronic signalling methods can be adapted to a UART. Such as RS-422 and RS-485. But not limited to those.

In short, they serve different purposes but they can be composed together to make a "system" that allows a data word (byte, typically) to be exchanged between two communicating devices using a specific type of electronic signalling as the medium between them.